# How can I make LTSpice calculate the transient response starting from a time different than t=zero?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, ltspice, spice, transient

I'm creating a schematic and I'm trying to simulate it using LTSpice.
However, my RC time constant is quite large, and I'd like Spice to simulate only from around 10ms onward. I know that if i set .trans to 10ms, it will simulate from then on as well, but it will still calculate everything for the values before, and my computer can't handle that - Spice has already crashed on me a couple of times today.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Forgot to mention, my input signal is a sine wave with amplitude 15 and 100k Hz frequency

Comment: Could you hand-calculate the voltage on the RC at t=10ms, and then set the voltage with an initial condition statement? Provided there isn't dependence on the state of other circuit elements this seems easiest. http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=IC_set_initial_conditions

Comment: What time step are you using?  For well behaved circuits you can increase the time step to speed up the simulation with minimal impact the quality of the results.  See https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-speed-up-your-simulations.html for general speedup tips.

Comment: Have you looked at .savebias and .loadbias?  See [here](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=SAVEBIAS_Save_operating_point_to_disk).